# Can I draw two horizontal bars in one line in Gantt chart using Microsoft Project?

Tags: microsoft-project, gantt

I would like to draw a task that start at A time and finish at B time, then start at C time and finish at D time.

That will produce a two horizontal bars in one line . is this possible using Microsoft  Project ??

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed.  This functionality is called Task Splitting.

I'm not sure what version of Office you are running, but here are a few tutorials you can work through:

[Project 2010](http://ntrajkovski.com/2011/05/02/how-to-split-tasks-in-ms-project-2010/) (Select The Task, Click Split button, drag the second part of the task)

[Project 2013](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Split-a-task-20c8581b-6266-45e3-af54-cc7c3b10deca) (Select Task, Schedule Group, Split Task, drag the second part of the task)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put two tasks on the same row. 
A split task is still only ONE task.

You can also summarise several tasks, roll them up, whilst showing the tasks and formatting the summary bar (and ends) as blank.
Note the links won't be shown and the summarised tasks will need to be formatted separately from their un-summarised cousins.

Both solutions work if you are merely "drawing" bars.
The roll-up will work with logic, but you'll have to unroll it to see what is going on.